# Azure Java Tomcat logging

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, azure, azure-diagnostics

I am planning to migrate a previously created Java web application to Azure. The application previously used `log4j` for application level logs that where saved in a locally created file. The problem is that with the Azure Role having multiple instances I must collect and aggregate these logs and also make sure that they are stored in a persistent storage instead of the virtual machines hard drive.

Logging is a critical component of the application but it must not slow down the actual work. I have considered multiple options and I am curious about the best practice, the best solution considering security, log consistency and performance in both storage-time and by later processing. Here is a list of the options:

- Using log4j with a custom `Appender` to store information in Azure SQL.
- Using log4j with a custom `Appender` to store information in Azure Tables storage.
- Writing an additional tool that transfers data from local hard drive to either of the above persistent storages.

Is there any other method or are there any complete solutions for this problem for Java?
Which of the above would be best considering the above mentioned criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to write a Log4J `Appender`. I didn't need to gather diagnostics information, my main goal was only to gather the log files in an easily exchangeable way. My first fear was that it would slow down the application, but with by writing only to memory and only periodically writing out the log data to Azure tables it works perfectly without making too many API calls.

Here are the main steps for my implementation:

First I created an entity class to be stored in Azure Tables, called `LogEntity` that extends `com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.TableServiceEntity`.

Next I wrote the appender that extends `org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton` containing a `java.util.List<LogEntity>`.

From the overrided method `protected void append(LoggingEvent event)` I only added to this collection and then created a thread that periodically empties this list and writes the data to Azure tables.

Finally I added the newly created `Appender` to my log4j configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

There's no out-of-the-box solution right now, but... a custom appender for Table Storage makes sense, as you can then query your logs in a similar fashion to diagnostics (perf counters, etc.).

The only consideration is if you're writing log statements in a massive quantity (like hundreds of times per second). At that rate, you'll start to notice transaction costs showing up on the monthly bill. At a penny per 10,000, and 100 per second, you're looking about $250 per instance. If you have multiple instances, the cost goes up from there. With SQL Azure, you'd have no transaction cost, but you'd have higher storage cost.

If you want to go with a storage transfer approach, you can set up Windows Azure diagnostics to watch a directory and upload files periodically to blob storage. The only snag is that Java doesn't have direct support for configuring diagnostics. If you're building your project from Eclipse, you only have a script file that launches everything, so you'd need to write a small .net app, or use something like [AzureRunMe](http://azurerunme.codeplex.com/). If you're building a Visual Studio project to launch your Java app, then you have the ability to set up diagnostics without a separate app.

There's a [blog post](http://blog.persistentsys.com/index.php/2012/06/02/windows-azure-diagnostics-for-java/) from Persistent Systems that just got published, regarding Java and diagnostics setup. <strike>I'll update this answer with a link once it's live</strike>. Also, have a look at [Cloud Ninja for Java](https://github.com/PersistentSys/cloudninja-for-java), which implements Tomcat logging (and related parsing) by using an external .net exe that sets up diagnostics, as described in the upcoming post.

Comment: Edited to clarify needing a separate .net app only when building apps from Eclipse projects, which don't have .net scaffolding code (per @Avkash's reference to WorkerRole.cs).

Comment: Just edited to include link. There are formatting errors, but they're being corrected by Persistent this week.

Answer (score 1):

Please visit my blog and download the document. In this document you can look for chapter "Tomcat Solution Diagnostics" for error logging solution. This document was written long back but you sure can use this method to generate the any kind of Java Based logging (log4j, sure )in Tomcat and view directly.

Chapter 6: Tomcat Solution Diagnostics

- Error Logging
- Viewing Log Files

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2010/10/29/windows-azure-tomcat-solution-accelerator-full-solution-document.aspx

In any scenario where there is custom application i.e. java.exe, php.exe, python etc, I suggest to create the log file directly at "Local Storage" Folder and then initialize Azure Diagnostics in Worker Role (WorkerRole.cs) to export these custom log files directly from Azure VM to your Azure Blob storage.

How to create custom logs on local storage is described [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411528.aspx)

Using Azure Diagnostics and sending logs to Azure blob would be cheapest and robust then any other method u have described.

Comment: In cases where deploying from Eclipse projects, there's no WorkerRole.cs. Just startup script.

Comment: What you can do is create diagnostics.wadcfg and configure the timers and diag setting and drop in your Role Root folder. When Azure role will start it will look for diagnostics.wadcfg in the root folder it will load the configuration and start the diagnostics.

Comment: Here is the link on how to use "Windows Azure Diagnostics Configuration File" -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg604918.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative;

Can we not continue using log4j the standard way (such as DailyRollingFileAppender) only the file should be created on a UNC path, on a VM (IaaS).
This VM, will only need to have a bit of disk space, but need not have any great processing power. So one could share an available VM, or create a VM with the most minimal configuration, preferably in the same region and cloud service.

The accumulated log files can be accessed via RDP/ FTP etc.

That way one will not incur transaction cost and 
cost of developing a special Log4j appender ... it could turn out as a cheaper alternative.

thanks
Jeevan

PS: I am referring more towards, ones application logging and not to the app-server logs (catalina/ manager .log or .out files of Weblogic)